# Determining Physical drive corresponding to Event Log atapi error on "IdePort1"

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, motherboard, sata

I'm seeing Error 11 "The driver detected a controller error on \Device\Ide\IdePort1" in the event log of a Windows 7 machine. 
The motherboard is a Gigabyte GA P35 DS4 v2. It has 6 SATA ports connected to the ICH9, and two Gigabyte SATA ports connected to a separate controller.

I'm trying to understand which drive corresponds to the "IdePort1" in the error message.

The term "IdePort" does not occur in the registry. 
In examining the disk controller and disk properties in Device Manager and Disk Management, I have found the following information:

The Boot drive properties are:

```
Location 0, Channel 1, Target 0, Lun 0
Parent: PCIIDE\IDEChannel\5&6882b60&0&1
Physical Device Object Name: \Device\Ide\IdeDeviceP1T0L0-1
Instance Path: IDE\DISKTOSHIBA_THNSNH256GBST___________________HTRAN101\6&15A9375D&0&1.0.0
```

Another drive has these properties:

```
Location 0, Channel 1, Target 0, Lun 0
Parent: PCIIDE\IDEChannel\4&23c85994&0&1
Physical Device Object Name: \Device\Ide\IdeDeviceP3T0L0-4
Instance Path: IDE\DISKST31500541AS____________________________CC34____\5&36A55C2A&0&1.0.0
```

In Device Manager, under IDE ATA/ATAPI controllers, there are three instances of "ATA Channel 0, followed by three instance of ATA Channel 1. I can find the drives in these listed under Detailed Properties "Bus Relations".

But there is nothing that indicates what number in all these strings corresponds to the "IdePort1"

Does the number in IdePort# correspond to Location, Channel, Target, or LUN? 
Or is it the number in the "physical device object name" string "IdeDeviceP1T0L0-1" or "IdeDeviceP3T0L0-4"?  Or something else?

Comment: This article <http://support.microsoft.com/kb/159865> seems to address the question, but it is for Windows 2000, and there is not an updated version. This KB addresses how to identify a message about a specific disk, not a disk controller.

Comment: Did you find an answer on this?

Comment: @tim11g it appears that article has moved to https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/159865

Comment: This thread on the MS support forums is regarding the need to update KB 159865: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows8_1-performance/updated-information-required-for-kb-159865/e74cd617-49f7-4725-b0ac-3c1cc7cbc3f7

Answer (score 2):

I would guess that for the Boot drive, "IdeDeviceP1T0L0" likely means "IDE device port 1 target 0 lun 0".

More info can be found in the Microsoft article
[Understanding Disk Location Paths](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee851589%28v=ws.10%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396),
which also explains how to display disk details using the utility diskpart.

Windows device information is to be found in the registry under the key
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Hardware\Devicemap`, that you could share here.

I remark that error 11 is usually either a bad SATA cable or a dying disk (not the only reasons).

Comment: Harry, that does seem like a reasonable guess. Is there any way we could make this certain?

Comment: I have not found any Microsoft document to that effect and only some passing references to that naming format. Examining the registry Devicemap and the info given by diskpart might throw some more light on the referred device and whether only one device can be referred-to by "IdePort1". I would still give very good chances for it being the boot drive.